# ASP.NET multiple databound dropdownlist issue

Tags: asp.net, exception, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a ASP.NET website that tracks computer assets and one page in particular lets the user update the data. This page has a Sqldatasource object for the GridView, as well as each dropdownlist in the GridView's edit mode. This page works beautifully until I changed one field from open text to a drop down, where the items in the drop down are dependent on the selected item of another column. Per record, there is a column for 'Site' and 'room' and the dropdownlist for room will change based on the chosen site. I also need to add a blank item to the top of the dropdownlist to support new/null records. To support null records, I changed the dropdownlist for the room column to AppendDataBoundItems = true so that I can add a blank item, and then the items retrieved from the sqldatasource are loaded after it. The issue with this implementation is that with each change of the site dropdownlist (and it's postback) a new list of room numbers will be appended to the room dropdownlist, which is not desired, the list should be cleared and reloaded on each change of the site column. In order to resolve this issue, I added the following code:

```
protected void DropDownListSite_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList drop = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("DropDownListSite");
        Session["atSite"] = drop.SelectedItem.Text;
        DropDownList roomdrop = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("DropDownListRoom");
        roomdrop.Items.Clear();
        roomdrop.Items.Add(string.Empty);
    }
```

Furthermore, when the room dropdownlist's value is databound, changing the site column will result in the exception:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
Stack Trace:
[InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.]
System.Web.UI.Page.GetDataItem() +2642054
ASP.viewassets_aspx.__DataBinding__control28(Object sender, EventArgs e) in <redacted path>\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\81f582e0\4392b2e5\App_Web_kyt9rnda.0.cs:0
System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +14
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +22
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +18
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

I assume this means that the main page thread crashed since the selected value of the room dropdownlist is no longer an item in the list.

Here is the code for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" 
        AllowSorting="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        style="text-align: center" onprerender="GridView1_PreRender" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="name" 
            EnableModelValidation="True" onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" 
            onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" AllowPaging="True">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField SelectText="Pop-&gt;" ShowEditButton="True" Visible="False" >
            <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
            </asp:CommandField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" 
                ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="model" HeaderText="model" SortExpression="model" 
                ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Age" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Check-in" HeaderText="Last Check-in" 
                SortExpression="Last Check-in" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ip" HeaderText="ip" SortExpression="ip" 
                ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="site" SortExpression="site">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSite" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSiteEdit" DataTextField="school" 
                            DataValueField="school" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Site") %>' 
                            AutoPostBack="True" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListSite_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="EditValidator" 
                            ErrorMessage="Required field" ControlToValidate="DropDownListSite"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("site") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="room" SortExpression="room">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListRoom" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRooms" DataTextField="roomName" 
                        DataValueField="roomName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("room") %>'
                        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListRoom_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        AppendDataBoundItems="True" ondatabound="DropDownListRoom_DataBound" 
                        onprerender="DropDownListRoom_PreRender">
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="DropDownListRoom" CssClass="EditValidator" 
                        ErrorMessage="Required field"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("room") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Function" SortExpression="Function">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Function") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Desktop</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Laptop</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="DropDownList3" CssClass="EditValidator" 
                        ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Function") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Local Printer" 
                SortExpression="Local Printer Type">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("[Local Printer Type]") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>InkJet</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Laser</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Impact</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="DropDownList4" CssClass="EditValidator" 
                        ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("[Local Printer Type]") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location Type" SortExpression="Location Type">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("[Location Type]") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Classroom</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Office</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Media Center</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Mobile Lab</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Fixed Lab</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="DropDownList5" CssClass="EditValidator" 
                        ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Location Type]") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Primary Use" SortExpression="Primary Use">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("[Primary Use]") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Admin</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Teacher</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="DropDownList6" CssClass="EditValidator" 
                        ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Primary Use]") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    &nbsp;
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Updated" HeaderText="Last Updated" 
                SortExpression="Last Updated" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FA_Number" HeaderText="FA_Number" 
                SortExpression="FA_Number" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Funding_Source" HeaderText="Funding_Source" 
                SortExpression="Funding_Source" ReadOnly="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

So my question is: How can I databind the datasource where the room column is dynamic based on the chosen site, and it will default to a blank (index 0) item in the list when the site column is changed and the selectedvalue is no longer an item in the list?

I apologize in advance if this is long winded or I left out something important, please feel free to ask questions for clarification.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please add the relevant code of the Gridview (from the ASPX page)

Comment: Added code block for the GridView, sorry i guess this would have been helpful the first time :s